# ¿Como puedo hacer para cambiar la imagen de un botón hasta que vuelva a ser pulsado?

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

Quiero hacer un `JButton` de silenciar sonido para una canción de forma que una vez se oprima cambie de forma hasta que vuelva a ser pulsado, pero no se como hacerlo, ya que el único factor que yo conocía para hacer esto era la propiedad de los botones, pressedIcon, pero esta solo es para el instante en el que es pulsado.

Comment: no has probado con un JToggleButton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la rutina de atención al click del botón puedes cambiar el icono. Por ejemplo, el programa principal es este, que lo único que hace es crear un diálogo que contiene un botón.

```
public class JavaApplication4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewJDialog n = new NewJDialog(null,false);
        n.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Y el diálogo, este, que lo único que hace es cambiar el icono cuando se clica el botón.

```
public class NewJDialog extends JDialog {

    public NewJDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    // y esta es la rutina que realiza el trabajo
    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        jButton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("A.png")));
    } 

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

En esta solución he obviado los imports. Yambién he quitado el código de initComponents(), generado automáticamente por el netbeans.

Ambas clases están en el mismo directorio src, donde además también hay el archivo A.png.

Espero que sirva.